# How to download the entire scored dataset from Azure machine studio?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have an experiment in azure machine learning studio, and I would like to the see entire scored dataset.

Naturally I used the 'visualise' option on the scored dataset but these yields only 100 rows (the test dataset is around 500 rows)

I also tired the 'save as dataset' option, but then file does not open well with excel or text editor (special character encoding)

Basically, I want to see the entire test data with scored labels as table or download as .csv maybe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try the Convert to CSV module: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/faa6ba63-383c-4086-ba58-7abf26b85814

After you run the experiment, right click on the output of the module to download the CSV file.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

use a convert to csv module first, then save the csv out.